# Bootstrap Grid Merge

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have two grids i'd like to merge seamlessly as one larger one.

Is there a way to force them to behave as if in one grid without breaking the current HTML structure.

Currently displaying as

Child[0]

Child[1] Child[2] Child[3]

Would like to show it as

Child[0] Child[1] Child[2] Child[3]

```
<div id="TNTemplate" class="row">
    <div id="Child[0]" class="col-md-4">First Instance of Stuff</div>
</div>
<div id="TNPlaceHolder" class="row">
    <div id="Child[1]" class="col-md-4"> First Clone of First Instance of Stuff</div>
    <div id="Child[2]" class="col-md-4"> Second Clone of First Instance of Stuff</div>    
    <!-- A bunch more rows  -->    
    <div id="Child[3]" class="col-md-4"> Tenth Clone of First Instance of Stuff</div>
</div>
```

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't without breaking the current HTML.

possible solutions:

- Put all divs in one row.
- Add new row that merges them.

  ```
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
         <div id="TNTemplate" class="row">
             <div id="Child[0]" class="col-md-4">First Instance of Stuff</div>
         </div>
       </div>
      <div class="col-md-8">
          <div id="TNPlaceHolder" class="row">
              <div id="Child[1]" class="col-md-4"> First Clone of First Instance of 
              Stuff</div>
              <div id="Child[2]" class="col-md-4"> Second Clone of First Instance of 
              Stuff</div>    
           <!-- A bunch more rows  -->    
              <div id="Child[3]" class="col-md-4"> Tenth Clone of First Instance of 
           Stuff</div>
      </div>
   </div>
  ```